# What is the use of libraries in android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support folder

Tags: android

There are some folders in the android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support folder which is my android sdk manager's location.

Can anybody tell me what use do they have?

Answer (score 0):

This folder contains your support libraries, which provide backward compatibility for Android APIs. You can find more details about support libraries [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html).

You can download the support library version you require from the SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

This folder contains support Libraries from maven Repository if you are using Android Studio (Gradle Build System).